# "Your unused Realtime Database will be deactivated in 14 day(s)" - how to fix access rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I had an email to say that my Firebase database would be de-activated in 14 days unless it receives traffic or I update my security rules. When I login to my Firebase account I don't see any options to maintain my database. The only option I get when I select the "Realtime Database" menu item is "Create Database".
How can I see and maintain an existing database?

Answer (score 9):

*firebaser here*

This message is sent to owners of databases that meet both of these conditions:

- Have world readable security rules AND
- Have not received any traffic in 6 months.

As the message says: to prevent the database from being deactivated you can:

- Either change its security rules,
- Or for it to start receiving traffic.

Note: your data will **not** be deleted either way.

---

I actually quickly checked one of my own projects that got disabled, and I see this in the console:

[image]

Clicking the <kbd>Re-enable</kbd> buttons seems to have reenabled the database without either of the two actions mentioned in the email. But I do expect the database to be disabled again, based on my lack of addressing the root cause.

If you're not seeing this same screen for your project, I'd:

- Reload the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/), and navigate to the database from there.
- If that still doesn't show you the same screen, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's not the screen I see when I login to my Firebase console and select the "Realtime Database" menu item. I'll submit a ticket to Firebase support as you recommend

Comment: Thanks for confirming. From what I understand from the team you might get the "create database" screen if (in addition to what's said above) your database is completely empty. Is that the case? If so, you might want to let the support engineers know that too.

Comment: Yes my database is empty - support are now aware of this

Comment: Hi Frank, I got a reply from Firebase support - thanks. Here's what they had to say:"
If you plan to use your Database, any operations will fix this. If you don't plan to use your database, then it is safe to ignore that email. This deactivation does not affect your usual usage. Also, the Database setup process will always reset as long as RTDB remains empty which might explain why you can't see the database. If you want to see your Database and Security rules, any data added to the database will prevent Database setup process to show again."  Have upvoted - thanks!